# Which game portals support Unity games?

Tags: unity, support

I'm considering development of some simple Unity games but am worried about distribution.  Which well known game portals currently support unity?

Comment: I like [GameJolt](http://gamejolt.com/).

Comment: [http://www.smashgamez.com](http://www.smashgamez.com) does support unity3d games. Check it out! ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Large community wiki list of that answer here: 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7558/which-game-portal-websites-accept-unity-webplayers.html

Answer (score -1):

we accept unity games and host them for free on [www.tinyutopia.com](http://www.tinyutopia.com). You can find submission information on our main page.